# ASP.NET MVC Url Masking/Rewriting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, cross-domain

Let us say I have a url of **subdomain.domain.com**.  Is there a way in ASP.NET MVC to have a url of say **otherdomain.com/gotothesubdomain** that takes you to **subdomain.domain.com**?  I know that a simple redirect could do it, but I want the url to stay as **otherdomain.com/gotothesubdomain**.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have 2 separate applications then you would need to grab the page as a string and then render it, here are some potential starting points - [WebRequest/WebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc.aspx), Html.RenderPartial in the mvc source or you could have a look at [JoeyB's](http://www.joeyb.org/blog/2010/01/23/aspnet-mvc-2-render-template-to-string) article.

It may be helpful to look at [Luke Sampsons](http://lukesampson.com/post/303245177/subdomains-for-a-single-application-with-asp-net-mvc) article that explains how to have multiple sub-domains in one mvc application, may help with your scenario?